# Blender Basic Bevel is Flat - Not Curved

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, bevel

Basic scene with mesh cube.  4 parallel outer edges are selected to round the cube.  A bevel is applied but here is no curve to the bevel.

Why? And what tiny settings do I need to correct?  And where are those settings in this massive UI?

Comment: hello could you please show a screenshot? Remember to apply the scale of your object before a bevel. Once you've beveled the settings are in the Operator box (bottom left)

Answer (score 2):

You can add bevel segments with the mouse wheel or the segments in the options that pop up bottom left of the view port when you confirm your bevel.  This will make them curved.

Comment: This was the answer.  Figured it out just messing around with the buttons.  I've seen this question asked in many ways, and no one ever gave this simple answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1871129 an even number of segments with a profile of 1 will also have no curve.